# How to support Windows authentication and OpenId in an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, openid

I have a Web API that currently supports Windows authentication out-of-the-box. In my `Startup.cs` I simply have:

```
services.AddAuthentication();
services.AddAuthorization();
```

and:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

That's all there is for now. Both Windows and anonymous authentications are enabled and all controllers have the `[Authorize]` unless the require anonymous. Most controllers have CRUD actions and each on each action I have a custom filter that checks against the DB if a user is allowed to perform the action.

This API serves a Winforms desktop app and users login with their domain account. So currently I pass their network credentials on each request, plus an extra token which I use to compare with their database user rights.

Now I have a requirement to add additional authentication schemes, starting with OpenId. I already have a second app that gets an access token from the auth server.

I've started with the following but it's not working:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddNegotiate(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {

    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration["Issuer"];
        options.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"];
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(Configuration["EncryptionKey"]))
        };
    });

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var builder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
    );
    builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    options.DefaultPolicy = builder.Build();
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The general steps are well documented and in detail it's impossible to answer with given information. In general: Your client app need to get an access token and add it to request headers. `AddJwtBearer()` is the starting point to handle those JWT tokens (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0): Btw. one option would be to accept only jwt and move all possible auth types to your auth server that creates those tokens. E.g. you auth server supports AD auth and creates a token on success.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your default authentication schema?

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddJwtBearer(o => ...
```